# I mistakenly deleted the .app file from products and .dsym

Tags: .app

I mistakenly deleted the .app file from products and .dsym file..I want to change the product name,i changed it in Bundle name and Build settings.I thought if i delete the app file it will create again with new name..but it is not creating it even..how should i create it.It is showing red ?Any help

Comment: Any chance you'll say what platform this is?

Answer (score 0):

Close Xcode and start again. This should fix. It fixed mine.